# I can't remove .html, extension

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

Hi I been searching for a way to get rid of the `.html` extension and they all say to create a `.htaccess` file which I have done and have placed the code in the file but it still doesn't work. I'm not sure if I'm saving in the correct area or I've got the the wrong code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: you should check your server config. it might possible your mod_rewrite dll is disable. you need to enable it. like case of apache server you can check in  httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*).html\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* http://localhost/html/%1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /html/(.*)\ HTTP/
   RewriteRule .* %1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,where would I place this code?

Comment: So i place all that code in my .htaccess file. I'm not sure I'm saving in the right area, I'm using Brackets software to create my website and just saved the .htaccess file in my website file is that right?

Comment: The `.htaccess` file typically goes in the root of your project.

Comment: Really sorry but I'm a beginner can you explain the root of project.

Comment: @user3660857 it means that if your server's root is public_html, then you place it in there. For some, it could be httpdocs and may differ from system to system.